# Undefined: When I try to pass props from one component to another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am Struggling to pass props between `VendoDetailBrief.js` and `VendersDetail.js` in react. In `VendoDetailBrief.js` I have list of product information rendered as a table. Each list of products have their own `cpe` value which I want to pass it to `VendersDetail.js` component. but when I try to pass `cpe` as a prop, I got `undefined` error.

FYI: In `VendersDetail.js` I have baseUrl api and I want `cpe` value and this baseUrl api to be concatenated and make a request.

Here is the code

`VendoDetailBrief.js`:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import HelpOutlineIcon from "@mui/icons-material/HelpOutline";
import axios from "axios";
import "./ModalVendors.css";
import VendersDetail from "./VendorsDetail";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
const VendorDetailsBrief = ({ setModalOpenVendors }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  const [clickedAsset, setClickedAsset] = useState();
  const [hide, setHide] = useState(false);
  const baseURL =
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/business_process/business-impact/vendor-product-detail";

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(baseURL)
      .then((response) => {
        setData(response.data);
      })
      .then(
        (response) => {},
        (err) => {
          alert("No Data To Show");
        }
      )
      .catch((err) => {
        return false;
      });
  }, []);
  const DisplayData = data.vendor_product?.map((vendor) => {
    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{vendor.vendor}</td>
        <td onClick={() => setClickedAsset(vendor.cpe)}>
          <Link to="/vendor_details">{vendor.product}</Link>
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  });
  return (
    <div className="modalBackgroundVendors">
      <div className="modalContainerVendors">
        <div className="titleCloseBtnVendors">
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              setModalOpenVendors(false);
            }}
          >
            X
          </button>
        </div>
        <div className="z-100">
          <div className="text-black">
            <div className="rounded overflow-hidden flex  justify-center items-center">
              <table class="GeneratedTable">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Vendor</th>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    {/* <th>CPE</th> */}
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>{DisplayData}</tbody>
              </table>
              {hide ? <VendersDetail clickedAssetName={clickedAsset} /> : null}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default VendorDetailsBrief;
```

`VendersDetail.js`:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import HelpOutlineIcon from "@mui/icons-material/HelpOutline";
import axios from "axios";
import VendorDetailsBrief from "./VendorDetailsBrief";
const VendersDetail = ({ clickedAssetName }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  const foo = "cpe:2.3:a:oracle:peoplesoft_enterprise:8.22.14";
  const baseURL =
    "https://services.nvd.nist.gov/rest/json/cves/1.0?cpeMatchString=" +
    clickedAssetName;
  alert(clickedAssetName);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(baseURL)
      .then((response) => {
        setData(response.data);
      })
      .then(
        (response) => {},
        (err) => {
          alert(err);
        }
      )
      .catch((err) => {
        return false;
      });
  }, []);

  const DisplayData = data?.result?.CVE_Items?.map((vender) => {
    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{vender?.cve?.CVE_data_meta?.ID}</td>
        <td className="w-96">
          {vender?.cve?.description?.description_data?.[0]?.value}
        </td>
        <td>{vender?.impact?.baseMetricV2?.exploitabilityScore}</td>
        <td>{vender?.impact?.baseMetricV2?.severity}</td>
        <td>{vender?.impact?.baseMetricV2?.impactScore}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  });
  return (
    <div className="z-100">
      <div className="text-black">
        <div className="rounded overflow-hidden flex  justify-center items-center">
          <table class="table table-striped ">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Description Data</th>
                <th>Exploitability Score</th>
                <th>Severity</th>
                <th>Impact Score</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>{DisplayData}</tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default VendersDetail;
```

I really appreciate your helps! Thanks!

Comment: I believe the issue you have is due to the async nature of useState. You are rendering the `<VendorDetails>` component regardless wether the prop you're passing to it exists or not. So add another condition to it to check if the `ClickedAssetName` is set or not. `{hide && clickedAsset ? <VendersDetail clickedAssetName={clickedAsset} /> : null}`

Comment: It doesn't work the way you said. any other suggestion? @jakehurt